# JMeter 1 user Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectionException Response message: Non HTTP response

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to learn load testing with JMeter(Very new). Using the tutorial to Build a Web Test Plan on the JMeter website and another youtube tutorial, I created an HTTP GET request to hit www.google.com/ but I get the following result:

```
    Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
    Sample Start: 2018-07-16 12:44:09 CDT
    Load time: 64018
    Connect Time: 64018
    Latency: 0
    Size in bytes: 2390
    Sent bytes:0
    Headers size in bytes: 0
    Body size in bytes: 2390
    Sample Count: 1
    Error Count: 1
    Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
    Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException
    Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connection timed out: connect
```

Here's my request:
[link to image since I don't have 10 reputation yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E067U.png)

Looking around other people are getting this issue but their issue is after 250+ users: [Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connection timed out: connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39507765/response-code-non-http-response-code-java-net-connectexception-response-messag)

However, I'm only trying to use one user and one thread, and I couldn't find anyone having the same error with only one user.

I set the Client implementation to HttpClient4 like the second answer suggests from [jmeter Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388993/jmeter-non-http-response-code-java-net-connectexception) but I still get the same issue.

Thanks in advance!

**Answer** Turns out it was because of our proxy server. Which was strange because I'm able to send request via postman and get responses. But I switched to a computer not on the proxy and everything is working now.

Comment: Can you share a snapshot from your request?

Comment: Added image via edit

Answer (score 2):

The problem you try to connect with HTTPS protocol on [non HTTPS port](https://serverfault.com/questions/705197/http-over-port-443-vs-https-over-port-80) as 80

> there is a strong convention to send http over port 80 and https over port 443

Remove port number value and it'll use default 443 port

Comment: Thank you for the response, I still get the issue when leaving the port area blank or setting it to port 443.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the screenshot , you are using 80 as port number for https connection that is the reason why you are getting non http response code. Give port number as 443 or leave it blank ..

TO know more about Load testing with JMeter please follow [this link](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-recording/)